# Python multiprocessing exits without exception when accessing shared value. Is this normal?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to share a string between processes with multiprocessing.Value(c_wchar_p, ""). Program exits unexpectedly without exception with code (0xC0000005). I am guessing that problem is somehow caused by main process trying to access memory of child process. Issue occurs only when ctypes c_char_p/c_wchar_p are used. Thread works fine. Is this expected beheavor?

Steps to reproduce:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import ctypes
import time


class ProcessExample:

    def __init__(self, proc: bool):
        self.shared_bool = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
        self.shared_string = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, "one")
        self.shared_byte = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, b"one")
        if proc:
            self.th_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.target, args=(self.shared_bool, self.shared_string, self.shared_byte))
        else:
            self.th_proc = threading.Thread(target=self.target, args=(self.shared_bool, self.shared_string, self.shared_byte))
        self.th_proc.start()

    @staticmethod
    def target(shared_bool, shared_string, shared_byte):
        shared_bool.value = True
        shared_string.value = "two"
        shared_byte.value = b"two"

    def print_values(self):
        self.th_proc.join()
        print(self.shared_bool.value)
        print(self.shared_string.value)  # Exits
        print(self.shared_byte.value)  # Exits


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # example = ProcessExample(False)  # Works
    example = ProcessExample(True)
    time.sleep(1)
    example.print_values()
```

Output

```
True

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: If you running your code from an IDE like e.g. vscode, try running it from a terminal first. Some IDE's don't seem to work well with `multiprocessing`/`subprocess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in `multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, "one")` and `multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, b"one")`. To have string/byte string initialized correctly, use [`multiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array):

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading
import ctypes
import time


class ProcessExample:
    def __init__(self, proc: bool):
        self.shared_bool = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
        self.shared_string = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_wchar, "one")
        self.shared_byte = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_char, b"one")
        if proc:
            self.th_proc = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=self.target,
                args=(self.shared_bool, self.shared_string, self.shared_byte),
            )
        else:
            self.th_proc = threading.Thread(
                target=self.target,
                args=(self.shared_bool, self.shared_string, self.shared_byte),
            )
        self.th_proc.start()

    @staticmethod
    def target(shared_bool, shared_string, shared_byte):
        shared_bool.value = True
        shared_string[:] = "two"
        shared_byte[:] = b"two"

    def print_values(self):
        self.th_proc.join()
        print(self.shared_bool.value)
        print(self.shared_string[:])
        print(self.shared_byte[:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    example = ProcessExample(True)
    time.sleep(1)
    example.print_values()
```

Prints:

```
True
two
b'two'
```

Comment: You do not have to specify the value when creating the array. Instead, you can submit an integer which informs the maximum length of string that can be stored in this array (which might be more useful here).

Comment: And just to add, because an explanation was missing, this happens because `Value` creates pointers to memory blocks relevant to current process only. If you reassign the memory contents from a subprocess, the memory address changes and previous pointers become irrelevant. The reason a `Array` works is because it has fixed space, therefore any reassignment is guaranteed to fit in the current memory block. Therefore, the memory address remains constant.